# Restarting a Coroutine ignore the yield WaitForSeconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have an IEnumerator for a coroutine that spawn object like this

```
public IEnumerator spawnCoroutine;
private float spawnObstacleTimer;

void Start () {
        spawnObstacleTimer = GameObject.Find("EventSystem").GetComponent<gameManager>().spawnObstacleTimer;
        spawnCoroutine = spawnObsCoroutine(spawnObstacleTimer);
        startSpawnCoroutine();
    }

public IEnumerator spawnObsCoroutine(float timer)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);
            spawnObs();
        }
    }

public void startSpawnCoroutine()
    {
       StartCoroutine(spawnCoroutine);
    }
public void stopSpawnCoroutine()
    {
        StopCoroutine(spawnCoroutine);
    }
```

And I start it on the Start() which it run fine. But I've put a collision detection to stop this Coroutine when triggered. Again this is running fine but it's when I call the OnCollisionExit() that restart the Coroutine with the function `startSpawnCoroutine()`; a new object is spawned immediatly and is ignoring the `yield return new WaitForSeconds()`

So how this happen? StopCouroutine should stop it all and when I restart it, it should wait for seconds before executing the spawn.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `StopCoroutine(spawnCoroutine)` could be better named `PauseCoroutine(spawnCoroutine)`, when you call start again it restarts from the last `yield` inside the routine.

Change your `startSpawnCoroutine()` function to start a new instance of the routine to get it to "start from scratch"

```
public IEnumerator spawnCoroutine;
private float spawnObstacleTimer;

void Start () {
        spawnObstacleTimer = GameObject.Find("EventSystem").GetComponent<gameManager>().spawnObstacleTimer;
        startSpawnCoroutine();
    }

public IEnumerator spawnObsCoroutine(float timer)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);
            spawnObs();
        }
    }

public void startSpawnCoroutine()
    {
       //Moved the creation of the IEnumerable in to this function.
       spawnCoroutine = spawnObsCoroutine(spawnObstacleTimer);
       StartCoroutine(spawnCoroutine);
    }
public void stopSpawnCoroutine()
    {
        StopCoroutine(spawnCoroutine);
    }
```